# C#: Error al convertir una clase C# a XML

Tags: c#, xml

Clase creada en c# es la siguiente:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Personas")]
    public class Personas {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Nombre")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Direccion")]
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Estado")]
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="NoCargo")]
        public object NoCargo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="NoClase")]
        public object NoClase { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="codigo")]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
    }
```

El siguiente codigo es el XML, que debo crear de foma automatica desde mi clase c#:

```
   <Personas codigo="">
        <Nombre>Juan Perez</Nombre>
        <Direccion>Jiron</Direccion>
        <Estado>45</Estado>
        <NoCargo/>
        <NoClase/>
    </Personas>
```

EL mi error se presenta al hacer el llenado de dados a mi clase c#:

```
       Personas oper = new Personas();
        oper.Nombre = "Juan Perez";
        oper.Direccion = "Jiron";
        oper.Estado = 45;
        oper.NoCargo = null;
        oper.NoClase = null;
```

Por favor su ayuda con mi error, gracias.

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: Ese error sale pq estas accediendo a una propiedad o método de algún objeto nulo

Comment: Ej obj.metodo(), si obj es nulo da error, ya que un objeto nulo no puede invocar ningún método, ya que ese objeto no existe hay que construirlo

Comment: Son declarados como objetos genericos no tengo sus propiedades:  `public object NoCargo { get; set; } 
        public object NoClase { get; set; }  pero en el xml me deben salir como <NoCargo/>
        <NoClase/>`

Comment: Pon todo el código involucrado para entendernos mejor

Comment: Entonces que guardas en nocargo y noclase

Comment: No los pongas como nulos,

Comment: @Japv no guardo nada solo tengo que mostrar  las etiquetas** <NoCargo/> <NoCargo/> **para enviar el XML asi es el requisito, el XML completo que debo enviar es el que esta líneas arriba.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116796/discussion-between-japv-and-daes).

Comment: Inicializar esos campos New NoCargo(), o dales otro tipo de datos que no sea object

Comment: Cambiando el tipo de dato de objeto a texto la propiedad igual me sale : Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto, de otra parte inicializando el objeto NoCargo oCargo = new NoCargo() , me sale el mismo error.